# Else If statements not running

Tags: javascript

I am trying to keep a variable within a range of numbers when the function is ran, but the if statement does not run.

I am trying to have the object move only if its between 0 and 50 , if the objects value X is trying to go to 55 it will not run the code, but the issue I am facing is if move.X value is 51 and move.Y is 7 nothing runs, I need it to where move.Y will still ran with the if statements, while move.X can only be ran backwards. (decreasing the numbers)

```
go(move) {
      if (move.X > 0 && move.X < 50) {
        if (move.Dir === "W") {
          move.X -= 1;
        } else if (move.Dir === "E") {
          move.X += 1;
        }
        if (move.Y > 0 && move.Y < 50) {
          if (move.Dir === "N") {
            move.Y -= 1;
          } else if (move.Dir === "S") {
            move.Y += 1;
          }
        } else {
          console.log("Too Far");
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: There are at least three `if` / `else if` statements in your code. Could you please be more specific in describing the behavior you are seeing vs. the behavior you expect? Also, the code you posted is not valid JavaScript code. Please post code that is valid before we can try to debug it.

Comment: move is a object instantiated from a class, with the properties of x,y, and direction. So I dont know why my code is not valid, because it runs without the if statements.

Comment: "it runs without the if statements" is super vague. See my comment above.

Comment: In other words: "Too Far" doesn't get logged and the object doesn't move, right?

Comment: @CI_noob, this is a very simple code, while your question is unclear

Comment: @JonasWilms yes That is correct.

Comment: @SergeyNarozhnyy I am trying to have the object move only if its between 0 and 50 , if the objects value is 55 it will not run the code, but the issue I am facing is if move.X is 52 and move.Y is 7 nothing runs, I need it to where move.Y will still run the if statements, while move.X can only be ran backwards. (decreasing the numbers)

Comment: @CI_noob, you're not completely clear anyway. First condition is met (move.X btw 0-50) in the 2nd line and it excludes move.X = 52 from execution, contradicting your first statement. So combined logic is to be like that: d

Comment: So break them apart ? @SergeyNarozhnyy

Comment: @CI_nook, yes. Or if Dir values are strictly associated with each coordinate (W and E with X, while N and S with Y), you just need one "early exit" and one switch statement

Comment: You need a final `else` for the outer `if` so you can know that the initial `if` was skipped. This is a good example of THE problem with nested if's. Next, your descriptions must be more precise; first so you make sure you know what the problem is and second so we can understand and help. for example "... X trying to go to 55..."  'Trying to'?  "Go X, Go! You can do it!"  There, I fixed it. NO. Better: "When X is <someValue> " or "When X is between <theVal> and <thatVal> inclusive..."  And finally, ALWAYS PAIR AN ELSE WITH IF's TO CATCH THE UNEXPECTED.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a different approach and check the position along with the wanted direction.

```
function go(move) {
    if (move.X > 0 && move.Dir === "W") move.X -= 1;
    else if (move.X < 50 && move.Dir === "E") move.X += 1;
    else if (move.Y > 0 && move.Dir === "N") move.Y -= 1;
    else if (move.Y < 50 && move.Dir === "S") move.Y += 1;
    else console.log("Too Far");
}
```

Comment: and if move.X < 50 and the direction is N ? This would not work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two problems:

1) If one of the values exits the range, e.g. X = -1, then there is no way to get back into the range again, as you block both directions in that case.

You should change your logic to only block the E if it reaches the left border and only the W if it reaches the right border, that way the object can be moved into the range again.

2) The last else part will only be executed if `move.X > 0 && move.X < 50` is false. All the other nested ifs won't enter that branch.

You could either not nest the if / elseifs as shown in Nina's answer, or you would have to add an else branch to every if.

Comment: Yes that is my issue before, as soon as I would go out the range, it would just keep saying I left the area.

Answer (score 0):

If move.Dir values are strictly associated with each coordinate (W and E - with X, while N and S - with Y), I would just try smth like:

```
function go(move) {
  switch(move.Dir) {
    case 'W':
        if (move.X > 0) { move.X -= 1; }
        break;
    case 'E':
        if (move.X < 50) { move.X += 1; }
        break;
    case 'N':
        if (move.Y > 0) { move.Y -= 1; }
        break;
    case 'S':
        if (move.Y < 50) { move.Y += 1; }
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: But when (for instance) X reaches 0, you are stuck

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, yeap, while this can be easily updated based on desired logic which is hard to get from CI_noob

Comment: this is the issue I am having @SergeyNarozhnyy I start at 0 by default, I am just triggering the else statement, I do not know how to fix this. I tried to use -1 but did not fix it. I am sorry I am not being clear, I thought I was in my first post.

Comment: @SergeyNarozhnyy the cordinates are from 50x50 with square. The max is x50,y50 and the starting point is x0,y0.

Comment: @CI_noob, what are the steps exactly? Do you start from (x: 0, y: 0) always?

Comment: Yes in the constructor of the class, I have set the values of x and y to 0; So every object will be 0,0 by default

Comment: @CI_noob, cool. Can X and Y get values below 0? If this square is 50x50, I assume coordinates can be only inside some matrix, like [[0, 50], [0, 50]] right?

Comment: @SergeyNarozhnyy no the values cannot go below 0. Also I do not have a matrix set up. Just doing this visual from the console.